# Infinite loop when calling the stack print function

Tags: c++, stack, output, infinite-loop

This program should takes a postfix arithmetic expression then compiles the values of that expression.. Each time an integer is read, its gonna get pushed into the stack.. Otherwise, Two integers would be popped if +,-,* is read.

```
class Stack {
    Node *head;

public:
    Stack() {
        head = NULL;
    };

    void push(int data);
    int pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    void print();
};

void Stack::push(int data)
{
    Node * temp = new Node(data);
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    delete temp;
}

int Stack::pop()
{
    int x = head->data;
    head = head->next;
    return x;
}

bool Stack::isEmpty(){
    return head == NULL;
}

void Stack::print(){
    Node * temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp;
}


int main() {

    Stack st;
    char exp [] = "23+", c;
    int i, a;

    for (i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++){
        c = exp[i];

        if (c == '+'&&!st.isEmpty()){
            a = st.pop() + st.pop();
            st.push(a);
        }
        else if (c == '-'&&!st.isEmpty()){
            a = st.pop() - st.pop();
            st.push(a);
        }
        else if (c == '/'&&!st.isEmpty()){
            a = st.pop() / st.pop();
            st.push(a);
        }
        else if (c == '*'&&!st.isEmpty()){
            a = st.pop() * st.pop();
            st.push(a);
        }
        else if (c == '0')
            st.push(0);
        else if (c == '1')
            st.push(1);
        else if (c == '2')
            st.push(2);
        else if (c == '3')
            st.push(3);
        else if (c == '4')
            st.push(4);
        else if (c == '5')
            st.push(5);
        else if (c == '6')
            st.push(6);
        else if (c == '7')
            st.push(7);
        else if (c == '8')
            st.push(8);
        else if (c == '9')
            st.push(9);

        cout << c << endl;
        st.print();
    }
    cin >> a;
    return 0;    
}
```

When I call the print function in main, I get an infinite loop as an output..
I tried looking for the thing that's causing an infinite loop but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why you `delete temp;` when it equal to NULL in the `Stack::print` method?

Comment: Better question : why do you `delete temp;` in your **`Stack::push`** function ???? That shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: Unlike Java, C++ doesn't have a garbage collector. If I don't delete it,  I'll get out of memory.. delete temp; is outside the loop.. I don't think its causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @Raghad I don't think you understood SHR's comment. He's suggesting temp would be NULL after exiting the while loop, so there is no need to delete it.

Comment: Well, apparently likewise, unlike Java, you need to spend time learning how C++ memory management works. That `delete` on a NULL pointer certainly isn't causing your infinite loop, but `delete temp;` in your `push` function will eventually invoke flat-out undefined behavior and most-certainly *can* lead to a self-referencing node and thus infinite loop.

Comment: Also in pop() you need to delete head immediately after you stored result into x.

Comment: @WhozCraig THANKS! I can get a clearer output now. I have never thought that deleting a pointer after using it would cause an infinite loop. Actually, I haven't deleted any pointers until my professor has told us to.

Comment: @TonyJiang I just tried deleting the head and it caused the program to stop right after showing the output. But the output was better. I did moved head to the next node by head=head->next;.. If I delete head, I will have nothing pointing to the first node.

Comment: @Raghad See SHR's answer regarding pop(), he used a temp to cache the node, then deletes it.

Comment: If you're curious how that delete in `push` may lead to a infinite loop, consider what happens if the *next* allocation returns the *same* address. Now `head` and `temp` hold the same address, and `temp->next = head` creates a self-referencing node. This repeats until the code that attempts to walk the linked list is executed, and a NULL terminator is never found.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh I got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. Using `delete` in `push()`:

   ```
   void Stack::push(int data)
   {
       Node * temp = new Node(data);
       temp->next = head;
       head = temp;
       delete temp;  // This needs to go.
   }
   ```
2. Not using `delete` in `pop()`:

   ```
   int Stack::pop()
   {
       // Problem 1.
       // What if head is NULL?

       int x = head->data;

       // Problem 2
       // The old value of head is gone. It's a memory leak.
       head = head->next; 
       return x;
   }
   ```

   You need:

   ```
   int Stack::pop()
   {
      if ( head != NULL )
      {
         int x = head->data;
         Node * temp = head;
         head = head->next;
         delete temp; 
         return x;
      }
      else
      {
         // Figure out what you want to do if head is NULL
      }
   }
   ```
3. Using `delete` in `print()`.

   ```
   void Stack::print(){
       Node * temp = head;
       while (temp != NULL){
           cout << temp->data << " ";
           temp = temp->next;
       }
       delete temp; // This needs to go.
   }
   ```
4. Missing user defined destructor. You need to delete the objects in the object. Otherwise, you are leaking memory. Something along the lines of the code below should work.

   ```
   Stack::~Stack()
   {
      while (head)
      {
         Node * temp = head;
         head = head->next;
         delete temp;
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get number 4. And could you tell me what do you mean by "// The old value of head is gone. It's a memory leak."?

Comment: @Raghad, if you don't implement the destructor, the memory allocated for the nodes will not be deallocated. I have a feeling you were to trying to do that in `push()` but that's not the right place. You need the allocated memory until you pop an item from the stack or the object goes out of scope.

Comment: @Raghad, regarding "// The old value of head is gone. It's a memory leak.",  let's say you have two items in the stack - 1 and 2. If you pop the top, the stack will have only 2. If you don't delete the node corresponding to 1, the memory allocated for that node is not deallocated and it is a memory leak.

Comment: That was really helpful. Everything is perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is suggestion for `push` and `pop`.

try to understand the logic.

```
void Stack::push(int data) 
{
    Node * temp = new Node(data);
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    //Do not delete temp; deleting temp will delete the new added Node
}

int Stack::pop() 
{ 
    Node* temp = Head;
    int x=head->data;
    head=head->next;
    delete temp; //here you free the released memory.
    return x;
}
```

Also, instead all the if/else, for each digit in your code, you can do as follows:

```
else if(c>=0 && c<=9){
     st.push(c-'0');
}
```

Comment: But I don't think that any number is getting pushed into the stack cus the print function is printing nothing. And in pop() you didn't use temp.. So I don't think we need to create a temp node and delete it.